# HEVC decoder port Android Warning: invalid conversion from 'signed char*' to 'char const*

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, hevc

I am trying to cross compile HEVC to Android https://hevc.hhi.fraunhofer.de/svn/svn_HEVCSoftware/trunk/
my native system is Ubuntu 12.04 32bit.
I created the target system using the standalone-toolchain of android-NDK r9c as follows

```
./make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-14 --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.6 --install-dir=/my-android-toolchain14
```

I added the following lines to ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=/home/asdf/Android/android-sdk-linux/tools:$PATH
export PATH=/home/asdf/Android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=/home/asdf/Android/android-ndk-r9c:$PATH
export PATH=/home/asdf/Android/my-android-toolchain14/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/home/asdf/Android/my-android-toolchain14/sysroot:$PATH
```

This is the modified makefile

```
#########################################################
# check CONFIG parameter
#########################################################

ifneq ($(CONFIG), LIBRARY)
ifneq ($(CONFIG), CONSOLE)
CONFIG_ERR = TRUE
endif
endif

#########################################################
# executables used
#########################################################

CPP     = /home/nih/Android/my-android-toolchain14/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++    #g++
CC      = /home/nih/Android/my-android-toolchain14/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc    #gcc
AR      = /home/nih/Android/my-android-toolchain14/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar     #ar
LD      = $(CPP)
ASM     = nasm  #assembler/disassembler for Intel x86

#########################################################
# output file names and version information
#########################################################

ifeq ($(CONFIG), LIBRARY)
# the libraries that can be created
STAT_DEBUG_OUT      = $(LIB_DIR)/lib$(PRJ_NAME)Staticd.a
STAT_RELEASE_OUT    = $(LIB_DIR)/lib$(PRJ_NAME)Static.a
DYN_DEBUG_OUT       = $(LIB_DIR)/lib$(PRJ_NAME)d.so
DYN_RELEASE_OUT     = $(LIB_DIR)/lib$(PRJ_NAME).so
#
else 
ifeq ($(CONFIG), CONSOLE)
# the executables that can be created
STAT_DEBUG_OUT    = $(BIN_DIR)/$(PRJ_NAME)Staticd
STAT_RELEASE_OUT  = $(BIN_DIR)/$(PRJ_NAME)Static
DYN_DEBUG_OUT     = $(BIN_DIR)/$(PRJ_NAME)d
DYN_RELEASE_OUT   = $(BIN_DIR)/$(PRJ_NAME)
#
endif
endif


#########################################################
# c compiler flags
#########################################################

# default cpp flags for all configurations
#CPPFLAGS          = -Wall -fPIC $(DEFS) -I$(CURDIR)/$(INC_DIR) $(USER_INC_DIRS)
CPPFLAGS           = -mthumb -fPIC $(DEFS)  -I$(CURDIR)/$(INC_DIR) $(USER_INC_DIRS) -Wall -Wshadow -Wno-sign-compare -fpermissive #-Werror 
########## 
# enforce 32-bit build : 1=yes, 0=no
##########
M32?= 0
ifeq ($(M32),1)
CPPFLAGS+=-m32
endif
##########

#
# debug cpp flags
DEBUG_CPPFLAGS    = -g  -D_DEBUG
#
# release cpp
RELEASE_CPPFLAGS  =  -O3 -Wuninitialized

#########################################################
# assembler compiler flags
#########################################################

# default asm flags for all configurations
ASMFLAGS          = -f elf $(DEFS)
#
# debug asm flags
DEBUG_ASMFLAGS    = -g
#
# release asm flags
RELEASE_ASMFLAGS  =



#########################################################
# linker flags
#########################################################

# linker flags for all
ALL_LDFLAGS       = -Wall

########## 
# enforce 32-bit build : 1=yes, 0=no
##########
ifeq ($(M32),1)
ALL_LDFLAGS+=-m32
endif
##########


ifeq ($(CONFIG), LIBRARY)
# linker flags for library
# LDFLAGS           = $(ALL_LDFLAGS) -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic
LDFLAGS           = $(ALL_LDFLAGS) -shared #-lgnustl_shared 
#
# debug linker flags for library
DEBUG_LDFLAGS     = -Wl,-soname,lib$(PRJ_NAME)d.so.$(VER)
#
# release linker flags for library
RELEASE_LDFLAGS   = -Wl,-soname,lib$(PRJ_NAME).so.$(VER)
#
else
ifeq ($(CONFIG), CONSOLE)
# linker flags for console
LDFLAGS           = $(ALL_LDFLAGS)
#
# debug linker flags for console
DEBUG_LDFLAGS     =
#
# release linker flags for console
RELEASE_LDFLAGS   =
#
endif
endif



#########################################################
# objects that have to be created
#########################################################

# the object types that have to be created      
RELEASE_OBJS  = $(OBJS:.o=.r.o)
DEBUG_OBJS    = $(OBJS:.o=.d.o)


#########################################################
# rules
#########################################################

# suffixes
.SUFFIXES: .cpp .asm .r.o .d.o

#########################################################
# assembler rules
#########################################################


# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.asm
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $(RELEASE_ASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.asm
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $(DEBUG_ASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR1)/%.asm
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $(RELEASE_ASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR1)/%.asm
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $(DEBUG_ASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR2)/%.asm
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $(RELEASE_ASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR2)/%.asm
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $(DEBUG_ASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR3)/%.asm
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $(RELEASE_ASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR3)/%.asm
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $(DEBUG_ASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR4)/%.asm
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $(RELEASE_ASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR4)/%.asm
    $(ASM) $(ASMFLAGS) $(DEBUG_ASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<



#########################################################
# c rules
#########################################################

# Generate dependency files during compilation
# see also: http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html
#    2005-01-25 Steffen Kamp (kamp@ient.rwth-aachen.de), RWTH Aachen
define COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_RELEASE
        $(CPP) -c -MMD -MF $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.d -MT $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.o $(CPPFLAGS) $(RELEASE_CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $(CURDIR)/$<
        @cp $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.d $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.P; \
                sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
                -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.d >> $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.P; \
                rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.d
endef
define COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_DEBUG
        $(CPP) -c -MMD -MF $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.d -MT $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.o $(CPPFLAGS) $(DEBUG_CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $(CURDIR)/$<
        @cp $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.d $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.P; \
                sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
                -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.d >> $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.P; \
                rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.d
endef
define COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_RELEASE_C
        $(CC) -c -MMD -MF $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.d -MT $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.o $(CPPFLAGS) $(RELEASE_CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $(CURDIR)/$<
        @cp $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.d $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.P; \
                sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
                -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.d >> $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.P; \
                rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.r.d
endef
define COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_DEBUG_C
        $(CC) -c -MMD -MF $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.d -MT $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.o $(CPPFLAGS) $(DEBUG_CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $(CURDIR)/$<
        @cp $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.d $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.P; \
                sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
                -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.d >> $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.P; \
                rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d.d
endef

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_RELEASE)

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_DEBUG)

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR1)/%.cpp
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_RELEASE)

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR1)/%.cpp
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_DEBUG)

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR2)/%.cpp
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_RELEASE)

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR2)/%.cpp
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_DEBUG)

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR3)/%.cpp
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_RELEASE)

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR3)/%.cpp
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_DEBUG)

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR4)/%.cpp
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_RELEASE)

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR4)/%.cpp
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_DEBUG)

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_RELEASE_C)

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_DEBUG_C)

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR1)/%.c
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_RELEASE_C)

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR1)/%.c
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_DEBUG_C)

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR2)/%.c
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_RELEASE_C)

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR2)/%.c
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_DEBUG_C)

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR3)/%.c
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_RELEASE_C)

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR3)/%.c
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_DEBUG_C)

# create release objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.r.o: $(SRC_DIR4)/%.c
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_RELEASE_C)

# create debug objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d.o: $(SRC_DIR4)/%.c
    $(COMPILE_AND_DEPEND_DEBUG_C)


#########################################################
# directory settings
#########################################################

ifeq ($(CONFIG), LIBRARY)
# directories that have to be created for a library
CHECK_DIRS = $(OBJ_DIR) $(LIB_DIR)
#
else
ifeq ($(CONFIG), CONSOLE)
# directories that have to be created for console and MFC
CHECK_DIRS = $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)
#
endif
endif


#########################################################
# targets
#########################################################

all:                check_errors debug release

debug:              check_errors \
                    $(CHECK_DIRS) \
                    $(STAT_DEBUG_OUT)

release:            check_errors \
                    $(CHECK_DIRS) \
                    $(STAT_RELEASE_OUT)


#all:               check_errors debug release
#
#debug:             check_errors \
#                   $(CHECK_DIRS) \
#                   $(DYN_DEBUG_OUT) \
#                   $(STAT_DEBUG_OUT)
#
#release:           check_errors \
#                   $(CHECK_DIRS) \
#                   $(DYN_RELEASE_OUT) \
#                   $(STAT_RELEASE_OUT)
#
#stat_debug:        check_errors \
#                   $(CHECK_DIRS) \
#                   $(STAT_DEBUG_OUT)
#          
#dyn_debug:         check_errors \
#                   $(CHECK_DIRS) \
#                   $(DYN_DEBUG_OUT)
#
#stat_release:      check_errors \
#                   $(CHECK_DIRS) \
#                   $(STAT_RELEASE_OUT)
#        
#dyn_release:       check_errors \
#                   $(CHECK_DIRS) \
#                   $(DYN_RELEASE_OUT)

##########################################################
# check for errors
##########################################################
check_errors:
    @if [ "$(CONFIG_ERR)" = "TRUE" ]; then\
        echo "Wrong CONFIG parameter specified: $(CONFIG)";\
        false;\
    fi


##########################################################
# create directories
##########################################################

$(OBJ_DIR):
    @if [ ! -d $(OBJ_DIR) ]; then\
        mkdir $(OBJ_DIR);\
    fi

$(LIB_DIR):
    @if [ ! -d $(LIB_DIR) ]; then\
        mkdir $(LIB_DIR);\
    fi

$(BIN_DIR):
    @if [ ! -d $(BIN_DIR) ]; then\
        mkdir $(BIN_DIR);\
    fi



##########################################################
# create output files
##########################################################

ifeq ($(CONFIG), LIBRARY)
#
# create static debug out
$(STAT_DEBUG_OUT): $(DEBUG_OBJS)
    $(AR) -crs $@ $(DEBUG_OBJS)
#
#
# create release debug out
$(STAT_RELEASE_OUT): $(RELEASE_OBJS)
    $(AR) -crs $@ $(RELEASE_OBJS)
#
#
# create dynamic debug out
$(DYN_DEBUG_OUT): $(DYN_DEBUG_OUT).$(VER) 
    ln -fs lib$(PRJ_NAME)d.so.$(VER) $@
#
# create dynamic debug out
$(DYN_DEBUG_OUT).$(VER): $(DEBUG_OBJS) 
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(DEBUG_LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(DEBUG_OBJS) -L$(LIB_DIR) $(USER_LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS) $(DEBUG_LIBS) $(DYN_LIBS) $(DYN_DEBUG_LIBS)
#
#
# create dynamic release out
$(DYN_RELEASE_OUT): $(DYN_RELEASE_OUT).$(VER)
    ln -fs lib$(PRJ_NAME).so.$(VER) $@
#
# create dynamic release out
$(DYN_RELEASE_OUT).$(VER): $(RELEASE_OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(RELEASE_LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(RELEASE_OBJS) -L$(LIB_DIR) $(USER_LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS) $(RELEASE_LIBS) $(DYN_LIBS) $(DYN_RELEASE_LIBS)
#
#
#
#
#
else
ifeq ($(CONFIG), CONSOLE)
#
# added linked libraries to target prerequisites - $(*_PREREQS) variables - to force relinking when libraries have been rebuilt
#    2005-01-25 Steffen Kamp (kamp@ient.rwth-aachen.de), RWTH Aachen
#
# create static debug out
$(STAT_DEBUG_OUT): $(DEBUG_OBJS) $(STAT_DEBUG_PREREQS)
    $(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(DEBUG_LDFLAGS) $(DEBUG_OBJS) -L$(LIB_DIR) $(USER_LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS) $(DEBUG_LIBS) $(STAT_LIBS) $(STAT_DEBUG_LIBS)
#
#
# create static release out
$(STAT_RELEASE_OUT): $(RELEASE_OBJS) $(STAT_RELEASE_PREREQS)
    $(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(RELEASE_LDFLAGS) $(RELEASE_OBJS) -L$(LIB_DIR) $(USER_LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS) $(RELEASE_LIBS) $(STAT_LIBS) $(STAT_RELEASE_LIBS)
#
#
# create dynamic debug out
$(DYN_DEBUG_OUT): $(DEBUG_OBJS) $(DYN_DEBUG_PREREQS)
    $(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(DEBUG_LDFLAGS) $(DEBUG_OBJS) -L$(LIB_DIR) $(USER_LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS) $(DEBUG_LIBS) $(DYN_LIBS) $(DYN_DEBUG_LIBS)
#
#
# create dynamic release out
$(DYN_RELEASE_OUT): $(RELEASE_OBJS) $(DYN_RELEASE_PREREQS)
    $(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(RELEASE_LDFLAGS) $(RELEASE_OBJS) -L$(LIB_DIR) $(USER_LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS) $(RELEASE_LIBS) $(DYN_LIBS) $(DYN_RELEASE_LIBS)
#
#
endif
endif

##########################################################
# delete all produced files
##########################################################

clean:
    /bin/rm -rf $(STAT_DEBUG_OUT)
    /bin/rm -rf $(STAT_RELEASE_OUT)
    /bin/rm -rf $(DYN_DEBUG_OUT)
    /bin/rm -rf $(DYN_RELEASE_OUT)
    /bin/rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)

ifeq ($(CONFIG), LIBRARY)
    /bin/rm -rf $(DYN_DEBUG_OUT).$(VER)
    /bin/rm -rf $(DYN_RELEASE_OUT).$(VER)
endif


##########################################################
# include dependency files
##########################################################

-include $(OBJS:.o=.d.P)
-include $(OBJS:.o=.r.P)
```

The compiler warnings I get are: `invalid conversion from 'signed char*' to 'char const*`
Later because of this issue `strstr` crashes

```
: error: call of overloaded 'strstr(Char [1024], const Char [22])' is ambiguous
/home/nih/HM-latest/build/linux/lib/TLibCommon/../../../../source/Lib/TLibCommon/TComSlice.cpp:1916:73: note: candidates are:
/home/nih/Android/my-android-toolchain14/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/string.h:61:15: note: char* strstr(char const*, char const*) <near match>
/home/nih/Android/my-android-toolchain14/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/string.h:61:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const Char [22] {aka signed char const [22]}' to 'char const*'
```

The code compiles and runs perfectly on the native system, by the way.

Is this issue because of lack of support of the basic C++ library?
Do I need to provide a different include PATH?
Since this is a huge code, the option to handle these warnings manually it's kinda out of the question.

Any tips would be appreciated, thanks for you time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toolchain was fine. I tried codeSourcery and a native arm-gcc compiler and they all had the same output.
The HM reference code was the issue. I used a previous version, HM 10.0 specifically, and I managed to cross-compile it without issues.

Answer (score 0):

it's a toolchain issue. probably you may suppress that kind of error by modifying your `Makefile`. or you may temporarily modify `TComSlice.cpp` where it calls `strstr()` by preparing its second argument as `char const *` rather than buffer of chars. or try to use another Android toolchain although I don't think they are different but who knows

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed 'arm-linux-gnueabi-g++' on my native system and produced the same warnings. I guess it has to do with the compiler, it doesn't support the switch from signed char* to const char* .Which results to this error: 'invalid initialization of reference of type 'const std::list<const signed char*>&' from expression of type 'std::list<const char*>' '
Should I try a different compiler? What alternatives are there?

Comment: Have you tried modifying `TComSlice.cpp` ? ps. is that actually warning represented as error or is it a pure error? as I've mentioned before, if it is a warning originally, you may suppress it in `Makefile` by setting appropriate flag

Answer (score 0):

I think that the -fsigned-char added to CPPFLAGS can solve the problem